# Bootstrap 3 Scrollspy Offset Not Working In IE9 and Later

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've ran into an odd issue that I cannot seem to resolve.

I am using Scrollspy with an offset (to offset the height of the navigation) to highlight nav links while scrolling on a single page site.

This works perfectly in all browsers (including IE10) but not in IE9 and later. In the affected browsers, the nav will not highlight until the div reaches the top of the window, rather than the offset I have set.

You can see the site here - http://bic.bldsvr.com/

The code I am using to add the offset is - `$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.nav-main', offset: 50});`

At this point I am beyond baffled as to why it won't work in IE9 and later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I determined the issue is resolvable by using both the data-offset="" in the body class, along side the javascript implementation. I found that both are needed to get full browser support. (oddly the body attribute doesn't work in many browsers (in my case) so using both methods was the best solution)